# CKEDITOR ASP.NET Custom Properties

Tags: asp.net, editor, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR in ASP.NET and I would like to create custom configurations on the buttons. This means that when the user presses the  image button , and the image dialog pops on, automatically some fields like 'Stylesheet classes' are ready written. This means that the client does not have to input such details every time he/she inserts an image but such content will be already predefined in the editor.

How can be this done?

Comment: Solution Found: Open the image.js which can be found in the CKEDITOR folder and change the default like the following link: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Default_Field_Values